# Grails Project missing Java library at runtime

Tags: grails, libraries

I was trying to add some Java Libraries (AWS SDK for Java, Apache Commons Math, etc.) to my Grails project since some of my Java source code (placed in src/java) had dependencies.  By following this answer, I was able to resolve compile errors by adding the jar files to the /lib folder and add it to the build path, as answered here: [Add Java Libraries to a Netbeans Grails Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294279/add-java-libraries-to-a-grails-project)

However, when I call my Java source code from my controller during runtime, it is unable to find the Java libraries that I added, showing a NoClassDefFoundError.  Should I be adding something to the BuildConfig.groovy file?  I'm not sure what the name convention for the jar files to be added to the dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you refer to is *5 years old*. You should use newer resources :)

The preferred approach now is to use dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy, and let Grails (via Ivy or Maven) download the jars for you once and reuse them for various projects.

It's not always obvious what the syntax is, and I find that http://mvnrepository.com/ is a great resource. For example if you search for "commons math" and click through to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math you'll see a few versions. Click on version 2.2 and you'll see the Maven dependency XML but you can click on the Gradle tab and it's going to be similar to what you need for Grails. So I'd add

```
dependencies {
   compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math:2.2'
}
```

and if necessary change `compile` to `runtime`, `build`, etc. depending on what you need the jar in the build process.

In the rare case that you do have a jar that isn't available in a Maven repo (e.g. a shared library at your company) then you can put the jar file in the lib directory. As you've seen, Grails doesn't auto-detect it (this is as of version 2.0). But you can run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` to get your jar added to the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the maven repository.  I did try both methods, but still having this NoClassDefFoundError despite setting up dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy.  The java source code runs just fine on its own, but not when called by a Grails controller.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` means that the class you're requesting is there, but that one or more of the classes that it depends on isn't. So you'll see that the code compiles fine, but fails at runtime. It's easily confused with `ClassNotFoundException`. Use http://mvnrepository.com/ to see what other dependencies you might be missing (although they should be transitively loaded by Ivy/Maven if using BuildConfig).

Answer (score 0):

My issue turns out to be the fact that AWS Java SDK had dependencies (Apache HTTP Client) that were not installed yet and that I was unaware of.

This is what I had to configure this for my BuildConfig.groovy file

```
dependencies {
   runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.5'
   runtime 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.4.7'
}
```

All the dependencies for AWS Java SDK 1.4.7 can be found here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.4.7.  All the dependencies outside of HTTP client were already installed for me, but may not be for your Grails setup.